# "sequence contains no matching element" on Group By operations in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Power BI newbie question here.

Whenever I add a *Group By* step with a *Text.Combine()* or a *Max()* aggregate, applying changes or refreshing data results in the aforementioned exception.

My datasource is a D365 dataverse connection, all queries run just fine until I add a step to group and aggregate. As an example, starting with a very simple query with 2 columns (demandId, kor_subcontractorbillnumber) I want to concatenate in a csv column all billNumbers related to a given demandId :

```
= Table.Group(#"Table Buffer", {"demandId"}, {{"BillNumbers", each Text.Combine([kor_subcontractorbillnumber],", "), type nullable text}})
```

As seen in the [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Eoz.png), the preview on screen seems correct : the expected result is displayed in the *BillNumbers* column, and no error is reported in the column quality indicators. All is fine...until I click *Apply*, which raises the exception.

I tried to clean the columns as much as possible before grouping (removing empty values, errors, duplicates, etc.), as well as adding an extra step to store results in a table buffer before grouping but with no luck.

Browsing through SO I found that similar issues could be related to :

1. *Wrong relationship cardinalities* : does not apply here I guess since everything is correct in the buffer table until I group
2. *Power Bi Desktop update* : some users have reported in the past that an update broke something and gave the same exception. In my case, the issue started occurring after upgrading to July 2022 version and unfortunately it seems I can't downgrade to a previous version. I've started using PowerBi in June and do not have much experience to detect whether the july update actually broke something, though some reports ceased functioning short time after the update.

Even stranger : If I remove the last step (*Group By*) and I create a new query referencing this one... [I can add a *Group By* step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prxg4.png) and apply my changes...until I Refresh my report : at this point **all** the embedded queries fail with the same exception, even those absolutely unrelated with my changes.

Could anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong or if you have experienced the same behavior with the last version of Power Bi desktop ( 2.107.841.0 64-bit), which could point me to the right direction ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Reading up on this, sounds mostly like a system issue needing reinstallation of the software

Comment: Unfortunately I've just uninstalled and reinstalled Power Bi desktop from the store...with no success. :-(

Comment: what happens with = Table.Group(#"Table Buffer", {"demandId"}, {{"BillNumbers", each try Text.Combine([kor_subcontractorbillnumber],", ") otherwise null }})

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the same exception occurs :-(

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I eventually stumbled upon a workaround: instead of the *Group By* step, I clicked on the very last step of my query and selected '*Extract Previous*'. This created a new query (result of all previous steps), and I was able to perform my *Group By* on this new query without any errors.

I have no idea how this is different from adding the *Group By* at the end of the first query... but the exception is gone. Kind of a code smell anyway...I mark my own question as answered in case it can help someone, but I'd more than happy if someone could shed some light on the underlying reason of this issue.